# can I reset an unbinded function with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, bind, unbind

Gosh, I'm on here a lot... Anyways, it's in the question. I have an unbinded function, and I need it to come back after a certain amount of time (preferably when a video has stopped playing, but now I'm just going for a certain amount of seconds).

I found someone with a problem similar to mine [here (on the jquery forums)](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/applying-bind-delay-unbind-seems-the-delay-is-ignored), and while I tried to apply the solution (the first response), it didn't work. here's what I tried to do

```
$('li', '.thumbs').bind('touchend click', playVideo);


$('li', '.thumbs').bind('touchend click', function() {
        //some code
        playVideo( $(this).index() );
        $("li", ".thumbs").unbind('click');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('li', '.thumbs').bind('touchend click');
            },5000);
        });
```

So, why?

**EDIT  okay, I got the bind to come back with the timeout, but for some reason it's not completing the function `playVideo`. It stops the video that's playing, but doesn't start the new one...

Comment: Are you saying that the binding of the onclick in the settimeout is not working?

Comment: @jmort253 yeah, that and the bind is not even coming back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('li', '.thumbs').bind('touchend click', onPlayClick);

function onPlayClick(){
    //some code
    playVideo( $(this).index() );
    $("li", ".thumbs").unbind('click', onPlayClick);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('li', '.thumbs').bind('click', onPlayClick);
    },5000);
}
```

Also, if you're using jQuery 1.7+, the `on()` / `off()` are preferred.
Example:

```
$('li', '.thumbs').on('click', onPlayClick);
$('li', '.thumbs').off('click', onPlayClick);
```

Comment: Hi ahren, can you show a quick example of on/off? Great suggestion! +1

Comment: In this case, on/off is pretty much the same - syntactically.

Comment: I did apply the `on()`/`off()` as you suggested, aand it works, so there's that....

Comment: One question, is it worth mentioning as well that 'on' is delegating, meaning that if Natasha adds more elements that match `li` and `.thumbs`, they'll automatically have the click event applied?  This may or may not be what she's looking for, and it might also be worth clarifying just in case someone else has questions about the differences. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Nata2haMayan2 - I updated the above, as the function names would have been clashing previously.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your setTimeout, you're not binding the element to a function. Add your callback function, and the problem will be resolved.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('li', '.thumbs').bind('touchend click', playVideo);  // added callback
},5000);
```

Remember, whenever you re-bind an event, you must explicitly pass it a function to call when the event is triggered, even if you've previously registered the event before and called unbind on that element's event.

Also, keep in mind that setTimeout and setInterval callback functions have global scope, meaning they have visibility at the "window" level. You'll need to make sure that the function playVideo is defined at the global scope where it is visible to the setTimeout.

Comment: this works, but for some reason the function is not working once it's "re-binded"

Comment: @Nata2haMayan2 - Please see the last paragraph. Is "playVideo" defined in the global scope?  Also ahren pointed out that you may be clashing your function names or using the wrong name. I don't see enough of your code to know for sure, but you should definitely check that out.

Comment: A troubleshooting step could be to bind something in that setTimeout bind event that you *know* works, like `function natashaWasHere() { alert("yo!"); }` and then pass `.bind("click",natashaWasHere);`. If the alert doesn't fire, then it's a scope issue, if it does fire, then maybe something specifically is wrong with the player. This could give you a place to start in your troubleshooting and help you narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should Work.

```
$('li', '.thumbs').bind('touchend click', playVideo);    
$('li', '.thumbs').bind('touchend click', function() {
    //some code
    playVideo( $(this).index() );
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('li', '.thumbs').unbind().bind('touchend click',playVideo);
        },5000);
    });
```

Because, In this case every time When time out is set then you have to unbind the previously bind function and then bind.Also there must be callback function  while binding.

Or You can trigger Click instead of binding if you know where to click.
For Eg if class thumbs is to be click.  Theen

```
  $('.thumbs').trigger('click');
```